# How can I use residential proxies in Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I have bought some residential proxies from proxies.gg.

How can I use them in the Python requests module?

Comment: Please show us your code and explain where in particular you're having difficulties. The `requests` documentation shows examples of how to use proxies so you should start there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the "proxies" argument in the requests module.

```
import requests

# configure the proxy
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://user:password@proxy_address:proxy_port',
    'https': 'http://user:password@proxy_address:proxy_port'
}

# make a GET request through the proxy
response = requests.get('https://www.example.com', proxies=proxies)

# print the response
print(response.content)
```

Comment: will this format work? g1LcDZuL:kPd68rosPX_session-58da3804_lifetime-24h@residential.proxies.gg:40000